# Solving problems regarding accessing localhost over LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, local-area-network, localhost

I have two computers with IP addresses of 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 respectively. Both computers have Apache servers installed on them and both are listening to port 8080 rather than 80. I have connected both computers via LAN and I am successful in pinging each other.

However, I am unable to access,  for example, MySQL database of one computer on the other via the LAN.

What are the required settings that should be altered??

Comment: Please clarify  ... I am unable to access localhost of one computer on the other.  Not sure what this even means.  What are you trying to access and how?

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Please see the updated question. Does it helps now??

Comment: Check your firewall settings.  Just realized this is a windows server, so that is a bit out of my expertise.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Well now I am able to access the wamp main page through another computer. Now I want to work from MySQL's console from 192.168.1.1 into the databases stored on 192.168.1.2. Is this possible?? Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities, depending on details about what you want to achieve. You need to go through a troubleshooting process to establish where the error is. Assuming that you have some webapp on apache that is attempting to reach mysql on the other machine, here are a few to check to get you going:

- Is mysql running?
- Is mysql configured to listen to TCP sockets?
- Is mysql listening on the external IP address?
- Is mysql authentication/authorisation configured correctly? (in other words, have you created a database/user, granted privileges and is your client offering the correct credentials?)
- Are there any firewalls between client & server?
- Is the webserver/webapp configured correctly?

You might want to consider connecting to the mysql server from the other machine using a command line mysql client, instead of the webapp, in order to help reduce complexities and to help show where the failure is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by installing phpmyadmin manually (preferably in c:) on both PCs and assign an Alias in httpd.conf file of your phpmyadmin installation. You can then access mySql through phpmyadmin using the browser. That's it.